# C# - HttpWebRequest POST (Registration to Facebook)

Tags: c#, facebook, post, get, httprequest

I'm trying to register the account to Facebook in my program. The code completed with out any error, but current account was not created... Tell me please, why an account was not created, and how I could to fix this...!? Thank you

```
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com");
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;

        string getUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/register.php";

        string postData = String.Format("lsd=AVqgs7ZA&firstname={0}&lastname={1}&reg_email__={2}&reg_email_confirmation__={3}&reg_passwd__={4}&birthday_day={5}&birthday_month={6}&birthday_year={7}&sex={8}&referrer=&asked_to_login=0&terms=on&ab_test_data=KAVAA%2FVqVVfVKKVAAAKKVAAAKAAAAKAAKAAAAAAANV%2FPHACCACTAAV&contactpoint_label=email_only&locale=ru_RU&abtest_registration_group=1&reg_instance={9}&captcha_persist_data=AZlzVAXpxSBvz2m12-Wi5UAOoI3amOVHCh7iFoM8M3egwA1-vKjn5ZWpe5bjhJ0D8w4qGzhxVdgfwCKCkOzgvp69BobnhTz5Ds3Vd_vU0zQFmRtj5w_82VTSc6xA7hwJhNkOkTUelZqD7NKVVhD_iPnGdL8gkFOSppfL7fQl5fCmHC5mhnu3sLzn9yvrl-UncMbF9XI7fOo5XXYjJF9ndxBN6hJkXaL5xzw7vwEio_YG6paqJMakAk5lp0OfRP-ECw7TDrDhB0AI2noQDC7jNjEqUydXEu9qfM0-vtesB65YkooDRDaNTiwQQDKctbFuf34p2YkfYVgRUG9Tk2StAZBPR9Z_AsguzTO-am-oSdlL6w&captcha_session=9mFp7RbABIHRwifiXdnNnQ&extra_challenge_params=authp%3Dnonce.tt.time.new_audio_default%26psig%3DTqQWE5U0FyBbKdh-OCiQMJnqNcE%26nonce%3D9mFp7RbABIHRwifiXdnNnQ%26tt%3DPwlZs1PTkRGaWAZetE7A2iTpMHA%26time%3D1404336540%26new_audio_default%3D1&recaptcha_type=password&captcha_response=&ignore=captcha&__user=0&__a=1&__dyn=7wiXwNAwZwzx6bGeBzozLFwioiw&__req=9&__rev=1314552", 
            "Olegius", "Karantinov", "olegikaran123321@ukr.net", "olegikaran123321@ukr.net", "passpass", "12", "3", "1994", "1", cookies);

        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies); //recover cookies First request
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();
```

Comment: Did you read Facebook API documentation? Usually registering new accounts programmatically isn't supported by any production website for security and spam reasons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Facebooks policies doesn't allow it